# `nuget.exe update -self` not doing what I expect

Tags: nuget

In my .nuget, I have a fairly old NuGet.exe. I last updated it in early April (before 2.5 was even released). I decided that I needed to update it to the latest.

So, first I updated the extension in Visual Studio to 2.7.40808.167.  Then, I ran the following in bash, from my solution's .nuget directory:

```
$ nuget.exe update -self
Checking for updates from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.
Currently running NuGet.exe 2.7.0.
Updating NuGet.exe to 2.7.1.
Update successful.
```

Well, that's odd. The current version should have been something like 2.2.  Oh well, at least it's updated now, right?

```
$ nuget
NuGet Version: 2.7.40906.75
usage: NuGet <command> [args] [options]
Type 'NuGet help <command>' for help on a specific command.
```

That seems good, but:

```
$ git status
# On branch nuget
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r--    1 sandy    Administ      169 Mar  7  2013 NuGet.Config
-rwxr-xr-x    1 sandy    Administ    18432 Apr  9 09:06 NuGet.exe
-rw-r--r--    1 sandy    Administ     3800 Mar  7  2013 NuGet.targets
```

Strange, the exe has not been updated. There is no other nuget.exe in my PATH...let's run `update -self` again:

```
$ nuget.exe update -self
Checking for updates from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.
Currently running NuGet.exe 2.7.0.
Updating NuGet.exe to 2.7.1.
Update successful.
```

So, this is strange:

1. My old nuget.exe is claiming to have an impossibly new version.
2. No matter how many times I run `update -self`, I keep being told that it is upgrading from 2.7.0 -> 2.7.1.
3. The actual nuget.exe binary is not changing.

Any idea what's going on? I'm sure I could simply download a new nuget.exe binary and be fine, but I'd like to understand the current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about this, it is a bug.  When checking the current version, we read the assembly metadata, and when we published 2.7.1, we failed to update the assembly metadata.  You have the latest, it just doesn't know it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to get that far with downloading it directly.  It looks like it's a bug.  I'm noticing the same issue.  Downloaded it directly, version 2.7.0.  Rename .nuget\nuget.exe to something else and run update -self and it still only downloads 2.7.0

Comment: That answers the question about 2.7.0 -> 2.7.1, but I still don't understand why my NuGet.exe binary hasn't actually changed.  It's still some very old 2.x version.